# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND parishackers.org parishackers.org:80

Tags: node.js

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND parishackers.org parishackers.org:80 error happens.
I wrote the codes,

```
var Crawler = require("node-webcrawler");
var url = require('url');

var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections : 10,
    // This will be called for each crawled page
    callback : function (error, result, $) {
        // $ is Cheerio by default
        //a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log($("title").text());
        }
    }
});

// Queue just one URL, with default callback
c.queue('http://www.amazon.com');

// Queue a list of URLs
c.queue(['http://www.google.com/','http://www.yahoo.com']);

// Queue URLs with custom callbacks & parameters
c.queue([{
    uri: 'http://parishackers.org/',
    jQuery: false,

    // The global callback won't be called
    callback: function (error, result) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log('Grabbed', result.body.length, 'bytes');
        }
    }
}]);

// Queue some HTML code directly without grabbing (mostly for tests)
c.queue([{
    html: '<p>This is a <strong>test</strong></p>'
}]);
```

but when I run the code,
Google
Yahoo
Amazon.com: Online Shopping for Electronics, Apparel, Computers, Books, DVDs & more

```
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND parishackers.org parishackers.org:80
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'parishackers.org',
  host: 'parishackers.org',
  port: 80 }
```

error happens. I think program scrape data part of it, but I do not know why program can do it completely. I installed library like npm install node-webcrawler. I read another site, so I think this error happens because of wrong link, right? How should I fix this? What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Try to visit http://parishackers.org with your browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error `(getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND parishackers.org parishackers.org:80)` is throwed because of invalid domain http://parishackers.org. Use valid url links, your node webcrawler will works like a charm. Modified the snippet for your reference

```
var Crawler = require("node-webcrawler");
var url = require('url');

var c = new Crawler({
    maxConnections : 10,
    // This will be called for each crawled page
    callback : function (error, result, $) {
        // $ is Cheerio by default
        //a lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log($("title").text());
        }
    }
});

// Queue just one URL, with default callback
c.queue('http://www.amazon.com');

// Queue a list of URLs
c.queue(['http://www.google.com/','http://www.yahoo.com']);

// Queue URLs with custom callbacks & parameters
c.queue([{
    uri: 'http://www.amazon.com',
    jQuery: false,

    // The global callback won't be called
    callback: function (error, result) {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log('Grabbed', result.body.length, 'bytes');
        }
    }
}]);

// Queue some HTML code directly without grabbing (mostly for tests)
c.queue([{
    html: '<p>This is a <strong>test</strong></p>'
}]);
```